# Blowfish algorithm openssl Android Native

Tags: android, c, openssl, java-native-interface, blowfish

**I try to use blowfish algorithm base on opensll. Then have a problem follow. 
This is my Encrypt function**

```
unsigned char* enc(unsigned char *key, const char *intext) {

    unsigned char* bfbuf = (unsigned char*) malloc(1024);
    unsigned char* b64buf = (unsigned char*) malloc(1024);
    unsigned char *newbuf;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    int outlen = 0, tmplen;

    /* EVP_Encode*() Base64 */
    EVP_ENCODE_CTX ectx;
    int len, total = 0;

    printf("\nEncrypting string...");
    EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx, EVP_bf_ecb(), key, NULL);
    if (!EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, bfbuf, &outlen, (const unsigned char*) intext,
            strlen(intext))) {
            return 0;
    }
    if (!EVP_EncryptFinal(&ctx, bfbuf + outlen, &tmplen)) {
            return 0;
    }

    outlen += tmplen;
    LOGI("Encrypted String")
    LOGI((const char* )bfbuf)

    /* Base64 using EVP */
    printf("\nEncoding string...");
    EVP_EncodeInit(&ectx);
    EVP_EncodeUpdate(&ectx, b64buf, &len, bfbuf, outlen);
    total += len;
    EVP_EncodeFinal(&ectx, b64buf + len, &len);
    total += len;
    LOGI("BASE64   Encrypted String")
    LOGI((const char* )b64buf)
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

    return (b64buf);
}
```

**And this is my decrypt function**

```
unsigned char* de(unsigned char *key, unsigned char* base64) {

    /* base64 string, encrypted string, pure text string */
    unsigned char* inbuf = (unsigned char*) malloc(1024);
    unsigned char* bfbuf = (unsigned char*) malloc(1024);
    unsigned char* ascbuf = (unsigned char*) malloc(1024);
    unsigned char* outbuf = (unsigned char*) malloc(1024);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    int outlen, tmplen;
    /* Base64 EVP_Decode*() */
    EVP_ENCODE_CTX ectx;
    int len, total = 0;

    /* Base64 decodification */
    printf("\nDecoding string...");
    EVP_DecodeInit(&ectx);
    EVP_DecodeUpdate(&ectx, bfbuf, &len, base64, strlen((const char*) base64));
    total += len;
    EVP_DecodeFinal(&ectx, bfbuf + len, &len);
    total += len;

    LOGI("base64 Decrypted")
    LOGI((const char* ) bfbuf)

    LOGI("\nDecrypting string...");
    EVP_DecryptInit(&ctx, EVP_bf_ecb(), key, NULL);
    if (!EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, (unsigned char*) ascbuf, &outlen,
            (const unsigned char*) bfbuf, 1000)) {
        LOGI("DecryptFinal failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    LOGI("firts")
    LOGI((const char* )ascbuf)
    if (!EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx, (unsigned char*) ascbuf + outlen, &tmplen)) {
        // EVP_DecryptFinal() still fail when password is too big.
        LOGI("DecryptFinal failed.\n");
        //return 0;
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    LOGI("Encrypted Message")
    LOGI((const char* )ascbuf)
    return ((unsigned char*) ascbuf);
}
```

**My encrypt function will encrypt message then convert to Base64. Then Decrpyt function will unbase64 then decrypt message.
This is my sample JNI function**

```
NIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_testjni2_NativeLib_blowfish(
        JNIEnv * env, jclass) {
    unsigned char key[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

    unsigned char *mystr =
            (unsigned char*) "hello world @#$%&()_ 123465788 test";

    unsigned char* converted = enc((unsigned char*) key, (const char*) mystr);

    LOGI("in time")
    LOGI((const char* )converted)

    jstring hande = env->NewStringUTF( (const char*)converted);
    LOGI("in jstring")
    return (hande);
}
```

**It's work fine.
But when i want to send Base64 Encryption String to Java, then Java will send Base64 to another function to decrypt --> It's totally failed
My function like this**

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_testjni2_NativeLib_blowfish(
        JNIEnv * env, jclass) {
    unsigned char key[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

    unsigned char *mystr =
            (unsigned char*) "hello world!@#$%&()_ 123465788 test";

    unsigned char* converted = enc((unsigned char*) key, (const char*) mystr);

    LOGI("in time")
    LOGI((const char* )converted)

    jstring hande = env->NewStringUTF( (const char*)converted);
    LOGI("in jstring")

    return (hande);
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_testjni2_NativeLib_deblowfish(
        JNIEnv * env, jclass, jstring str) {

    unsigned char key[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };   
    const char* converted =(const char*) env->GetStringUTFChars(str,0);

    unsigned char* out = de((unsigned char*) key, (unsigned char*)converted);
    LOGI("OUT time")
    LOGI((const char* ) out)

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str,converted);
    return env->NewStringUTF(out)
}
```

**I show LOGI to debug problem, and compare all, The encrypt message on deblowfish() totally like the encrypt message in blowfish() but when decrypt is wrong. And i still dont know why when devide encrypt and decrypt to two function, it's not work. 
Anyone have ideas?

Comment: So it looks like encryption/decryption is OK. But its not clear if the problem you are having is with Base64 or JNI. What is the problem you are having (other than "it does not work")?

Comment: Problem i got is the the send data beetween Java and JNI. When decrypt, the result is symbol like this �G�~��~��\�d�\�3Tx�I���c�z���=�_G�1��K5H܋�?��џSWd/*'z_6���"�Dt���څ.#�1��aТ��mz�!��. But when do encryt and decrypt in one function in JNI and dont have a transfer data beetween Java android and JNI. It's works fine

Comment: Have you tried to call `enc()` and `de()` back-to-back, without going out to Java? Simply add call to `de()` to your implementation of `com.example.testjni2.NativeLib.blowfish()` and log the result.

Comment: I tried. Everything's OK. Only when i push Encrypted Message to java and send back to Decrypt, it's fail.